# How to trim video exactly at the middle of Iframe using Mp4Parser?

Tags: android, iframe, trim, mp4parser

I'm trying to use Mp4Parser to trim video in my Android app. But problem is: I can not cut exactly at position which I want. For example: if I choose position of trimming is the 5th second, the video is still the same as before cutting. I understand that: the reason is that: my Iframe is from 0 to 10th second. But how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just use ffmpeg, mp4parser can't trim video exactly from, e.g., 5th second.

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:30 -t 00:01:10 -async 1 output.mp4`

From ffmpeg help:

```
-t duration         record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video
-ss time_off        set the start time offset
```

In conclusion, the link to [ffmpeg on Android project](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java).